# Initializing the base class of an extended class

Tags: java

Suppose there are three classes `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
public class A {
   int op1;  // op for operand
   int op2;
   int op3;

public A(int op1, int op2, int op3) {
   this.op1 = op1; 
   this.op2 = op2;
   this.op3 = op3;
}

public A(A a) {
   // Is this valid?
   this = a;
 }
}

public class B extends A {
   public B(int op1, int op2, int op3) {
   super(op1,op2,op3);
 }
}

public class C extends A {
   private ArrayList<Integer> array;
   public C(B b) {
   // Can the base class be initialized without 
   // calling the constructor that initializes each
   // attribute individually?
   super(b);
   array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 }
}
```

Is it possible to invoke the base constructor using the object received as a parameter in class C's constructor?

Comment: No it's not possible.  This is a pretty simple syntax question which you could have answered yourself by trying it.

Comment: So, when invoking the base class, is it not possible to initialize its value with an extended class (since B is an A)?

Comment: `this = a;` This makes no sense. `super(b);` This is ok/possible.

Comment: But super(b) calls the A's constructor with the instance b as an argument. How do I write the constructor so that it initializes the class with the instance b?

Comment: Look up how a "copy constructor" looks like (you're trying to creating one).

Comment: This is a bad design because of which you are confused. You want B to be its parent. In that case you should have directly subclassed B instead of A. Second thing, when we create constructors with parameters we must create no Arg constructor ourselves. If not, program won't run.

Comment: @SunilChakravarthy *"Second thing, when we create constructors with parameters we must create no Arg constructor ourselves. If not, program won't run."* What? You only create a non-parameterized constructor, if you need one.

Comment: In Java, if we don't create any constructor, by default a no Arg constructor is created in runtime and used. But when we define a constructor with arguments, then no Arg constructor won't be created automatically during runtime as it expects us to handle it. Try to call constructor with no Arg, it fails. You can try and check out

Comment: My intention here was to incorporate best practise. Even though it won't fail in the present scenario since they will only call using arguments. I got your point @Tom. It is not mandatory.

Comment: @SunilChakravarthy It is best to create only needed constructors, so if you don't need a non-parameterized constructor, then don't create one. This would only allow to create an instance in a state you don't like it in.